# setting the "DT_RowId" property when using simple_datatables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, datatables

I am using the [simple datatables](https://github.com/gryphon/simple_datatables) gem to integrate JQuery Datatables into my Rails App.

Is it possible to send the DT_RowId property in the json document as described in [the doc](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/ids.html) when using simple_datatables?